# Implementation of gdax-java as a library

Tags: java, bitcoin, gradlew, coinbase-api, gdax-api

I am trying to implement this API: https://github.com/robevansuk/gdax-java in order to be able to create orders, withdraw funds, and deposit funds via Coinbase and exchanging in GDAX for bitcoins. I am trying to make a trade program for Bitcoins using GDAX and its API.

However, I am very confused on the implementation of the library. I have tried to contact some contributors but they do not respond back. I read in their documentation:

> For a lib:
>
> If you'd rather work purely in java then you can build an executable jar file ./gradlew jar and you should be able to find the jar in the build directory.

So I cloned the project and ran the command

[image]

However, I was not able to find a jar in the build directory. It didn't generate any jar:

[image]

I checked, the only jar is the gradle wrapper. **Does anyone have any examples of implementation of gdax-java as a library?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my working copy... I tend to push any relevant changes back to the originating repository which is linked to from the Coinbase/GDAX website. https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java - please use this one as the main one as any work/issues should be raised on that repo.

Saying that... I wasn't expecting this lib to pick up so much attention and only just realised very recently people are trying to use it more widely now. Since there is a bit of a community building and its been forked more than a handful of times you should know, we're on the [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/irufus/gdax-java) linked to at the top of the original repository here: [gdax-java](https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java)

In terms of generating a jar - there are a number of ways to find it... one is to perform a search within the project directory...

```
cd [project_dir]
find . -name gdax-java.*jar
```

Alternatively it should be generated under the project dir `./build/gdax-java-[VERSION].jar`