# How do I import gdax-Java into my android studio app

Tags: android, gdax-api

I downloaded the git hub for gdax-java to my MacBook.

I don’t see any .jar file or a .aar file to import into my android studio app

There is no gradle dependency listed in the repository

How do I use this api in my android studio app?

I even tried  ./gradlew jar and I get this error
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.

Why is this so difficult to implement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementation of gdax-java as a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787085/implementation-of-gdax-java-as-a-library)

Comment: I tried that too and I get   
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do.  https://dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-11-on-macos

Then the steps of ./gradlew build  and ./gradlew jar worked and I could add the jar to the libs folder following these steps.  [How to add a jar in External Libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660166/how-to-add-a-jar-in-external-libraries-in-android-studio)

It would be nice if the ./gradlew steps would be indicated in the github